# function to check size of a Map in apache-drill

Tags: apache-drill

Is there anyway to check the size of a Map data type in `apache drill`?

the below works on `hive`.

```
select size(cdrlist) from somet_table;
```

where cdrlist is of type array.

But when the same table is accessed via drill, it will be of type Map but size or `REPEATED_COUNT` doesn't work on MAP data type.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Drill doesn't have this function. You can write your Custom Function and use it:
https://drill.apache.org/docs/develop-custom-functions-introduction/

The point that Drill can use Hive's inbuilt functions, such as `if`, `last_day` .. 
But `size` can't be used because of Drill doesn't support Hive complex data types yet :
[DRILL-3290](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-3290)